# Why is my "mapDispatchToProps" not able to find my action function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The specific errors I have been getting have varied with changes that I have been making, however, the current one I have is "Actions may not have an undefined type...". I am very new to using Redux, but I have been scouring the internet for anything that is consistent enough for me to follow.

TLDR: What I am trying to do is simply send a list of objects that look like the following: records: [{date: blah, ...., var: blah}, {...}]
to the global state so I can use it in all parts of my full application.

I have tried changing the mapDispatchToProps method in various ways, but I still am having a very hard time trying to connect it all.

I tried modifying the App.js, and the actions, reducers and store files accordingly but it all seems to be the same as the tutorial I was following. shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcC8KZ_Ga2M

The following is all the relevant code:

App.js
'''

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
createStackNavigator,
createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import MainScreen from './screens/MainScreen';
import CostAnalysis from './screens/CostAnalysis';
import DriverLog from './screens/DriverLog';

// REDUX IMPORTS
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { recordReducer } from './reducers/recordReducer';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: MainScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    }},
  CostAnalysis: {screen: CostAnalysis},
  DriverLog: {screen: DriverLog}
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

const store = createStore(recordReducer);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default (App);
```

'''

MY Second screen which I am navigating to and sending data to in this example
'''

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  YellowBox,
} from 'react-native';

// REDUX IMPORTS
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const device = Dimensions.get('window');

class CostAnalysis extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <Text>Hey you got here!</Text>
                <Text>{this.props.records[0]}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: {
        height: device.height - 60,
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0
    }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        records: state.records
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CostAnalysis);
```

'''

MainScreen.js

'''

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  YellowBox,
} from 'react-native';

// REDUX IMPORTS
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ADD_RECORD from '../actions/types';
import {addRecord} from '../actions/index';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import SpecialInput from '../components/SpecialInput';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import SpecialText from '../components/SpecialText';
import GenericButton from '../components/GenericButton';

const devWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const devHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

class MainScreen extends Component {

componentWillMount() {
  YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
    'Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated',
    'Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated',
  ]);
}

// State stuff
state = {
  date: 'Date',
  dateColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
  starting: '',
  ending: '',
  gasPriceCurrent: '',
  visible: false,
}

stringifyNumbers = (inputObj) => {
    return inputObj.toString().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
}

handleDateConfirm = value => {
  this.setState({
    date: value.toString().substring(4, 15),
    dateColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
  });

  // Hide the date picker
  this.hideDatePicker();
}

handleStartChange = (value) => {
  this.setState({
    starting: value
  });
}

handleEndChange = (value) => {
  this.setState({
    ending: value
  });
}

handleGasChange = (value) => {
  this.setState({
    gasPriceCurrent: value
  });
}

hideDatePicker = () => {
  this.setState({
    visible: false
  });
}

showDateTimePicker = () => {
  this.setState({ 
    visible: true,
    dateColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)'
  });
}

recordEntry = () => {

  const record = {
    date: this.state.date,
    startKM: this.state.starting,
    endKM: this.state.ending,
    curPrice: this.state.gasPriceCurrent
  }

// This is where I try to add the record to the list
  this.props.addRecord(record);

  // Now go to confirmation
  this.props.navigation.navigate('CostAnalysis');
  // Reset input fields after recording entry
  this.resetInput();
}

// Reset input fields
resetInput = () => {
  this.setState({
    date: 'Date',
    dateColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
    starting: '',
    ending: '',
    gasPriceCurrent: '',
    visible: false
  });
}

render() {
  return (
        <LinearGradient 
          colors = {['#051937', '#A8EB12']}
          style ={styles.homeScreen}
          locations = {[0.23, 1]}
          start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
          end={{x: 0, y: 1}}>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Hello</Text>
          <Text style={styles.subHeading}>
            Please start recording your starting and ending gas amounts
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showDateTimePicker}>
              <SpecialText
                  content = {this.state.date}
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 22,
                    color: this.state.dateColor
                  }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <DateTimePicker
              isVisible={this.state.visible}
              onConfirm={this.handleDateConfirm}
              onCancel={this.hideDatePicker}
            />
            <SpecialInput
              placeholder = {"Starting"}
              iconName = 'ios-car'
              iconText= '  KM'
              maxLength={3}
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              value={this.state.starting}
              placeholderTextColor={'rgba(255,255,255, 0.6)'}
              onChange = {this.handleStartChange}
            />
            <SpecialInput
              placeholder = {"Ending"}
              iconName = 'ios-car'
              iconText= '  KM'
              maxLength={3}
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              value={this.state.ending}
              placeholderTextColor={'rgba(255,255,255, 0.6)'}
              onChange={this.handleEndChange}
            />

            <SpecialInput
              placeholder = {"Current Gas Prices"}
              iconName = 'ios-pricetags'
              iconText= '  cents'
              maxLength={5}
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              value={this.state.gasPriceCurrent}
              placeholderTextColor={'rgba(255,255,255, 0.6)'}
              onChange={this.handleGasChange}
            />

            {/* Record the entry into data storage */}
            <GenericButton 
              style={styles.recordButton}
              textColor={'#ffffff'}
              placeholder = "RECORD"
              onPress={this.recordEntry} />

            {/* RESET BUTTON */}
            <GenericButton 
              style={styles.clearButton}
              textColor={'#ffffff'}
              placeholder = "CLEAR"
              onPress={this.resetInput} />
          </View>
        </LinearGradient>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        records: state.records
    }
}

// Here is where I noticed most of the errors pointing to
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      addRecord: (record) => {
        dispatch(addRecord(record))
      }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainScreen)
```

'''

my recordReducer.js

'''

```
// recordReducer.js

import { ADD_RECORD } from '../actions/types'

const initialState = {
    records: ['Chicken Joe']
};

const recordReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_RECORD:
            return {
                ...state,
                records: state.records.concat(action.value)
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export {recordReducer};
```

'''

actions/index.js
'''

```
import ADD_RECORD from './types';

// Add Record Action
export const addRecord = record => {
    return {
        type: ADD_RECORD,
        payload: record
    }
}
```

'''

actions/types.js

'''

```
export const ADD_RECORD = 'ADD_RECORD';
```

'''

As mentioned previously, I just want to figure out how to save the data in the store and retrieve it later from any component/screen/view.

Thanks so much for anyone who attempts to help me! I've been on this for a straight 12 hours now :(

EDIT 1:

This is the new error I'm getting. Only change is that in `actions/index.js` I have done a proper `named import`.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhAm9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `actions.js`.  You're importing:

`import ADD_RECORD from './types';`

But, that is a *default import*, whereas `types.js` is doing a *named export*:

`export const ADD_RECORD = 'ADD_RECORD';`

You need to use matching import and export syntax, otherwise the imported value will be `undefined`.  That's causing the action object to have an undefined `type` field, and thus the Redux error.

So, change `actions.js` to use a named import instead, as you have in your reducer file:

`import {ADD_RECORD} from "./types";`

Also, while the code you have atm works, you can simplify the `mapDispatch` definition in `MainScreen.js` to use [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object):

`const mapDispatch = {addRecord};`

As a side note, I'd highly encourage you to use [our new Redux Starter Kit package](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/), which automatically generates action types and action creator functions for you so you don't have to write them by hand.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your response I’m going to test it out right now! I’ll write back here whether it was successful!

Comment: Thank you so so much for your response I’m going to test it out right now! I’ll write back here whether it was successful!

Edit1: So I changed the issue you found in `actions/index.js`, but I am now encountering another issue that seems connected. I will update my post to include the new error if that helps?

Comment: The new error is a completely different issue.  The problem is you're trying to access `this.props.records[0].startKM`, but it looks like the `records` array is empty.  So, `records[0]` returns `undefined`, and you can't access `undefined.startKM`, so that throws an exception.  You need to modify your logic so that you check to see if that object actually exists first.